# Can I convert 0.16, 0.32, etc. into an integer properly (16, 32, etc.) in C?

Tags: c, casting, int, double

I'm trying to convert the decimal portion of a double `247.32`
into an int `32`. I only need two decimal places.

I can cast the double as int and subtract from the double to get `.32000`

I can then multiply by 100 to get `32.000`

But then when I try to cast that `32.000` as an `int`, it turns into `31`.

Can I fix this?
Should I use a different datatype than a double to store that number?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a set number of decimal places? You could cut a substring off the end then cast the string to an int?

Comment: I'm just looking for two actually

Comment: If it'll always be 2 decimal places, you can substring the 2 digits from the end. Otherwise you might need to find the `.` then substring 2 character after it. I don't know C syntax well enough to actually write you an answer for this however. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem (which skjaidev's answer doesn't solve) is that `247.32` cannot be represented exactly in binary floating-point.  The actual stored value is likely to be:

```
247.31999999999999317878973670303821563720703125
```

So you can't just discard the integer part, multiply by 100, and convert to `int`, because the conversion *truncates*.

The `round()` function, declared in `<math.h>`, rounds a `double` value to the nearest integer -- though the result is still of type `double`.

```
double a = 247.32;
a -= trunc(a);      /* a == 0.32 -- approximately */
a *= 100.0;         /* a == 32.0 -- approximately */
a = round(a);       /* a == 32.0 -- exactly */
printf ("%d\n", (int)a);
```

Or, putting the computation into a single line:

```
double a = 247.32;
printf("%d\n", (int)round(100.0 * (a - trunc(a))));
```

Actually, this is probably a cleaner way to do it:

```
double a = 247.32;
printf("%d\n", (int)round(100.0 * fmod(a, 1.0)));
```

Comment: This will work assuming the input value is "approximately" equal to a whole number of 1/100 units. If however the goal is to round an arbitrary input to the nearest number of 1/100 units, your algorithm fails corner cases that are almost exactly halfway between two 1/100 units, because the multiplication by 100.0 is non-exact, thus causing double rounding to occur.

Comment: Of course, if the integral part of the input is greater than 4 bits wide, the multiplication by 100.0 will be exact, so that's another case where your algorithm works.

Answer (score 2):

Given input value `x` and output `y`:

```
char buf[5];
snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "%.2f", fmod(x, 1.0));
y = strtol(buf+2, 0, 10);
```

Or just `y = 10*(buf[2]-'0')+buf[3]-'0';` to avoid the `strtol` cost.

This is about the *only* way to do what you want without writing **a ton** of code yourself, since the `printf` family of functions are the only standard functions capable of performing decimal rounding.

If you have some additional constraints like that `x` is very close to a multiple of 1/100, you could perhaps cheat and just do something like:

```
int y = ((x+0.001)*100;
```

By the way, if your problem involves money, **do not use floating point for money**! Use integers in units of cents or whatever the natural smallest unit for your currency is.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're only looking for 2 decimal places, this works for me:

```
double a = 247.32;
int b = (int) (a * 100)%100;
printf ("%d\n", b);
```

**Update**: See my comment below.

Comment: Thanks. That ended up working for me too. I was subtracting the `double` from the `int` version and then multiplying by 100. Then finally I'd cast to int. 0.16 would become 15, 0.32 would become 31, etc.

Comment: That printed `31` when I tried it. The conversion from `double` to `int` truncates, and `247.32` cannot be represented exactly.

Comment: @KeithThompson is right, I hadn't linked to the math library. If you link to the math library (-lm) you'll see what Keith describes.

Comment: @skjaidev: I'm surprised linking to the math library or not makes a difference. In fact, I get `31` on one system and `32` on another; `-lm` vs. no `-lm` makes no apparent difference.

Comment: Whether you get 31 or 32 depends on `FLT_EVAL_METHOD` and (if it's equal to 2) the properties of `long double` on your particular system.